# Refresh the List box with new rooms from the server every 3 seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

So i have a server which I send a Request to and it sends me back a list of rooms,Now i made a window for joining rooms and I'm trying to refresh it every 3 seconds but when i use the Timer thread to refresh the list it doesn't work if I use the normal refresh method with the Timer it works just fine.
Here's some code:

```
private void AutoRefresh()
{
   System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000).TotalMilliseconds);
   timer.AutoReset = true;
   timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.Refresh);
   timer.Start();
  }

private void Refresh(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg)
{
    GetRoomsResponse response;
    response = SendAndRecv();
    Button temp;
    foreach (RoomData room in response.rooms)
    {
        temp = new Button { Content = room };
        temp.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        JoinRoomClick(sender, e);
    };
        temp.Content = room.Name;
        buttons.Add(temp);
    }
ListBoxRooms.ItemsSource = buttons;
}
```

If I call refresh from the main it works perfectly if I call AutoRefresh it doesn't I think it gets stuck on the for each loop no error's just doesn't do it's job

Comment: Could it be a question for stack overflow instead? Not sure if code review is a good place to solve your problem/

Comment: We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).